# Getting Users from MongoDb using Node.js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nodes

I want to get the users info in my MongoDb using Noe.js. I'm able to get the data from a particular collection with the below code:

```js
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("mydb");
  dbo.collection("customers").findOne({}, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result.name);
    db.close();
  });
});
```

In the same manner I want to get the database users (i.e admins) details.

Any suggestions ??

Thanks in Advance!!

Regards

Ravi Kumar

Comment: do you mean you want to get the single user

Comment: @PeterWilson, I mean "I want to all the users' info that are created in my mongodb ". I just want to how many active users are there in my mongodb. I want all the usernames and passwords

Comment: So you can use `find` instead `findOne` and you'll get an array

Answer (score 0):

```
 dbo.collection("customers").find()
```

Will return all users and info from this collection

*Note: It will return result as an array*

```
 dbo.collection("customers").count()
```

Will return how many users are there in collection

Comment: Actually in the code I was not getting the "users". It was an example of getting collection with name "customers". Here "customers" is a collection and it is like a table. But I'm asking users info. 'dbo.collection(collectionName)` will give collection info. I'm asking question like "Is there any function which we can call like `dbo.users()' which will give users info?"

Comment: Your question is poorly worded then. I am still unsure what exactly you need

Comment: I'm asking "how to get database users". I tried my best to convey my question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a database called admin created automatically when you install Mongodb and it contains the admins and their roles for the other databases
you can access it via

```
var dbo = db.db("admin");
```

use this link https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/#create-a-user-defined-role to learn how to add and manage admins

Comment: You are right "change of fiendOne to find". I accept it. My question is entirely different. Actually in the code I was not getting the "users". It was an example of getting collection with name "customers". Here "customers" is a collection and it is like a table. But I'm asking users info. 'dbo.collection(collectionName)` will give collection info. I'm asking question like "Is there any function which we can call like `dbo.users()' which will give users info?"

Comment: you mean database users like admins?

Comment: Finally you got my exact question. That's what I need.